# Grothendieck's "List of classes of structures"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, topos-theory

In Lawvere's article *Comments on the Development of Topos Theory*, the author writes:

> Similarly, Grothendieck and others unerringly recognized which kinds of mathematical structures are 'preserved by all functors which preserve finite limits and arbitrary colimits'. (A very impressive list was produced by Grothendieck [47] during his 1973 stay in Buffalo; during the same visit he advocated the abandonment of his earlier complicated definition of 'scheme', but unfortunately the simpler alternative he offered does not seem to have found its way into the textbooks.)

The reference in the bibliography reads:

[47] A. Grothendieck, List of classes of structures, 1973 (now in J. Duskin's file.)

Can anyone direct me to a copy of this document? I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: I like your question, and I love your picture.

Comment: I too would be interested in this document.

Comment: And what's the simpler alternative definition of scheme?

Comment: @FanZheng it is the [functor of points](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/functor+of+points) approach. Grothendieck urged to abandon the previous definition in favor of this more functorial one.  Some illuminating information about the petit and gros toposes can be found [here](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2009/01/petit_topos_gros_topos.html).

Comment: Why not email the categories mailing list also? And/or Duskin himself?

Comment: @DavidRoberts I don't know any of these things/people and I'm not a professional mathematician so it feels a little rude to mail someone  with whom I've never interacted just asking for a document.

Comment: @Arrow then I will do it on your behalf!

Comment: If there is no copyright problem, it would be good to have a copy of this on an n-Lab page (Hint for David! ;-))

Comment: @Arrow, I've sent this email to the categories list. Like Tim, I would like it seen on the nLab. Given that AG's relatives have donated his Nachscrift, I don't foresee issues...

Comment: @DavidRoberts thank you very much. I hope you'll be able to share it with us soon.

Comment: @DavidRoberts have you had any luck?

Comment: @Arrow no! And, looking at the archives, I'm not sure it got through ... :-( Regarding AG's descendants, there are sadly nasty legal issues that have arisen, so I have to take that remark back.

Comment: @Arrow: For outsiders like me, what is meant by *"J. Duskin's file"*, please?

Comment: @AlexM. as an outsider myself, I have no idea! That's exactly how the reference appears in Lawvere's paper.

Comment: @Arrow: It seems that you are not the only one asking about this. There is [a similar discussion on MathForum from 2006](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4705566), that you might find useful and that might complement the answer here. A visually nicer presentation of the same discussion [is available on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math.research/4zC5HQ0tTqo).